# How to start ipython-notebook in Windows 7?

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, windows-7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed ipython with pip however I am unable to start ipython Notebook.
I am noob with python and have started learning not more than a week. 
I am trying to find out what I need to look for to troubleshoot.

Btw, I installed ipython with pip command, and I ran the command on windows powershell below:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Nimesh> ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

So, ipython is installed however I am not sure if there is anything else needed to install.

Comment: How are you trying to start ipython notebook and what error do you get when you try?

Comment: I tried with command line ipython notebook but it gives me an error. However stackoverflow won't allow me to upload image unless I have 10 points. I am pretty new here too.

Comment: Can you upload it elsewhere or write out what it's telling you?

Comment: You don't need an image, a simple copy-paste of the text will work just fine.  If you think you have dependency problems, you might try installing [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) - it should give you everything you need.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I installed Anaconda and now it's running as I expected. @Ajean Is there a way where I can give you a shout out for helping me? Let me know and I will be glad to do that.

Comment: @Nimish, no problem.  It's not really enough to warrant a whole answer (IMO) so just glad it helped.

Comment: What was the actual message? Why did installing anaconda solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're actually supposed to run "`ipython notebook`" to run the notebook server.

Comment: Could this be possibilities due to lack of Dependencies for the IPython HTML notebook? If so any workaround?